# Anaconda: Failed to find a suitable stage1 device

Tags: linux, installation, lvm, partition, anaconda

The installation is oversimplified here. In reality I want to format and supply all the disks (for swap, etc.) to anaconda with several `--disk` arguments to `virt-install` like it's suggested here https://serverfault.com/a/348408/518713. But I fail with the error `Failed to find a suitable stage1 device` every time. So I decided to simplify the whole installation and to start with one disk.

I supply an LVM disk to `virt-install`:

```
$ lvs
  LV      VG      Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root test_vg -wi-ao---- 100.00g
```

```
$ virt-install \
    --name perf-test-vm \
    --os-type=Linux \
    --os-variant=almalinux8 \
    --memory 20480 \ 
    --vcpus=2 \
    --location=/var/tmp/AlmaLinux-8.6-x86_64-minimal.iso \
    --graphics=none \
    --console pty,target_type=serial \
    --noautoconsole \
    --extra-args console=ttyS0 \
    --disk path=/dev/test_vg/lv_root \
    --network network=default \
    -v
```

```
virsh console perf-test-vm
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]